# Custom css to odoo tree view button

Tags: css, treeview, odoo-10

```
.o_list_view1 {
   tbody> tr> td {               
     .button-scrape {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        background: #7c7bad;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      }

      .glow-button:hover {
        color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 15px black;
      }
    }
 }
```

Its a less file, if i try to write a normal css file and try loading the class in the tree view its not loading

```
<button string="LINK" **class="o_list_view1 button-scrape glow-button"** icon="fa-external-link" name="openURL" type="object" />
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample of what you have tried before.

Comment: Show the traceback or console error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

odoo one2many fields will not respond to the css added .As odoo will load its own css for one2many or tree view. we need to override the base css class in our custom css file in order to change it or update it.

here is the example css to update the list button and notebook .

```
.o_list_button:hover {
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px black;

}


.nav-tabs:hover{
     color: black;
     box-shadow: 0 5px 15px black;


}
```